# What command can testfor a player looking up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What command can test for a player looking straight up?

Answer (score 2):

The selector arguments `rx` (X rotation maximum) and `rxm` (X rotation minimum) will let you test for a player with a certain vertical rotation. In this case, as -90 is the furthest up you can look, the command you want should be:

```
/testfor @a[rxm=-90]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that would detect anything below zero, for looking straight up you would use:

```
/testfor @a[rx=-90]
```

I would use

```
/testfor @a[rx=-50]
```

though